# "The UserId field is required" - entity validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

i'm using ASP.Net identity base on Entity framework for my MVC(5) app.

problem :

when i want to register a new user , i get a  Entity validation error.
i looked at the validation error property and i get 2 error(both the same actually) on this line :

```
         var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Errors :

http://i62.tinypic.com/11acy0y.png

now.....i have no idea where is this 'UserId' field coming from.
i looked at IdentityUser base classes and it does not belong to that either , there is just an "Id" field which works properly.

if more info is needed just mention in Comment plz.

So does anyone have any idea....what is this field ? and how to solve this?

**Edit** :
forgot to mention i create a base user in seed method of dbinitializer....that works fine. but in controller i get this error.

Controller & related Action :

```
    //
    //POST : /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> register(Register_ViewModel model)
    {
        UserManager.UserValidator = new MyUserValidation();

        //Complete User Object if Model is Valid
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        var user = new Employee
        {
         .......
        }

        //Store Claims
            ........


                // Where i get the error
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, IsPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }                             
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

View :

```
     @model Univercity_Project.Models.ViewModels.Register_ViewModel

     @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Register_tab";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
     }

     <h2>Register_tab</h2>


     @using (Html.BeginForm("Register","Account",FormMethod.Post)) 
     {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Employee</h4>
    <hr />
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <!-- Some Nav Tabs Here! -->
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- Nav-tabs Content  Here! -->  

        <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-     default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Employee(or 'ApplicationUser' ) model :

```
  public class Employee : IdentityUser
{

    public string Employment_Number { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public int National_ID { get; set; }

    public string First_Name { get; set; }

    public string Last_Name { get; set; }

    public string Father_Name { get; set; }

    public string Birth_Place { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birth_Date { get; set; }

    public string Serial_Alphabetic { get; set; }

    public int Serial_Numeric { get; set; }

    public int Number_of_People_Under_Support { get; set; }  

    //<----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    public virtual Employment_Status Employment_Status { get; set; }
    public int Employment_Info_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Marriage_Status Marriage_Status { get; set; }
    public int Marriage_Info_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Job_Status Job_Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Academic_Status Academic_Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Phone_Number Phone_Number { get; set; }

    public virtual War_Record War_Record_Info { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual Insuarance Insuarance_Info { get; set; }


}
```

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question by adding the html form that initiates the post to your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here is the solution :

in the part that i was adding Claims i didnt know that i should assign value to UserId Property here is what i was doing :

```
                    user.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim() { ClaimType = ClaimTypes.Gender, ClaimValue = user.Gender});
```

and here is what i should have done :

```
                    user.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim() { ClaimType = ClaimTypes.Gender, ClaimValue = user.Gender, UserId = user.Id });
```

Answer (score 0):

Has the Id field been set to Identity within the EF mapping for your User POCO:

`Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

EDIT:

I will Include my comment in this answer, which led to the solution:

there are other places where the userId is referenced. try adding the following to test as well: 
`user.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim {UserId = user.Id}); user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole {UserId = user.Id});`

Comment: as i said ID field works fine. my problem is with "UserId" field.

Comment: Have a look at the IdentityUserLogin object which has a UserID property. Try setting this as follows:

`user.Logins.Add(new IdentityUserLogin()
{
    LoginProvider = youValue1,
    ProviderKey = youValue2, 
    UserId = user.Id
});`

Comment: did it. still getting the Error.

Comment: Please post the Employee model definition

Comment: Employee Model added.also  register View has a view model. need that?

Comment: there are other places where the userId is referenced. try adding the following to test as well:
     `user.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim {UserId =  user.Id});
      user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole {UserId =  user.Id});`

Comment: did what u said.....now i get 3 Error .....new one say :   ErrorMessage "The RoleId field is required." string..
also i set userid as Claim in claimfactory :
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));